# Error: could not handle the request Angular 9 Universal + Firebase Function

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, angular-universal

I just deployed my angular 9 universal project to Firebase.

I'm getting this error while accessing my custom domain

> Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsDailyNonbillable' and limit 'CPU allocation in function invocations per day' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:256777508622'., Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsNonbillable' and limit 'CPU allocation in function invocations per day' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:256777508622'.); to increase quotas, enable billing in your project at https://console.cloud.google.com/billing?project= Function cannot be executed.

I just deployed my website and i'm the only one who is visiting the site. So I wanted to know why i'm getting error ?

Comment: The error says you exceeded the quota... Maybe your app made too many calls during tests ? Or too many data in DB, so a request took too much CPU... Hard to guess, you are the one who would better know what could have happened to use a lot of CPU...

Comment: I don't have DB, just Angular SSR function, I deployed default angular universal app

Comment: Oh, I thought Firebase was a DB feature. You only use it to host Angular Universal ? You should have a look to your Firebase dashboard, to see how many requests were handled, and you should spot the problem from here...

Comment: The message states that you exceeded [the quota for CPU]usage(https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#rate_limits). Either check your functions logic or request to increase the quota through console -> IAM & Admin -> Quotas.